# Render different fill/stroke colours depending on positive/negative x-axis value

Tags: data-visualization, vega

I'm trying to code a little chart for use in risk/opportunity analysis. You feed in 4 values:

- PreConsequence & PostConsequence (int's ranging -4 to +4)
- PreLikelihood & PostLikelihood (int's ranging 0 to 4)

And it visualises those with charts as follows:

[image: Risk / Opportunity Analysis Glyphs]

The shaded fill renders the **Pre** values, whilst the stroke renders the **Post** values. 
Geometry in the left quadrant represents risk and should be **red**, whilst geometry in the right quadrant represents **opportunity** and should be green.

I'm struggling to find out how to check for negative consequence values and assign colour accordingly. I think it'll be done in the last two lines of my code below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 250,

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"C": -4,  "L": 0, "f":"Pre"}, {"C": 0,  "L": 4, "f":"Pre"}, 
        {"C": 0,  "L": 2, "f":"Post"}, {"C": -1,  "L": 0, "f":"Post"}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "width",
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "C"},
      "domainMax": 4,
      "domainMin": -4
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "L"},
      "domainMax": 4,
      "domainMin": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range":"ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "f"}
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale", "tickCount": 10 },
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "yscale", "tickCount": 5, "offset": -250 }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "facet": {
          "name": "series",
          "data": "table",
          "groupby": "f"
        }
      },
    "marks": [
    {
      "type": "area",
      "from": {"data": "series"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "C" },
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "L"},
          "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0 }, 
          "fillOpacity": [{ "test": "indata('series', 'f', 'Pre')", "value": 0.3 }, {"value": 0}],
          "strokeWidth": [{ "test": "indata('series', 'f', 'Pre')", "value": 0 }, {"value": 2}],
          "fill": [{ "test": "indata('series', 'f', 'Pre')", "value": "red" }, {"value": "red"}],
          "stroke": [{ "test": "indata('series', 'f', 'Pre')", "value": "red" }, {"value": "red"}]
        }        
      }
    }
  ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone give me some pointers as to how to test the data values & set fill & stroke colours accordingly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vega signals can be used to conditionally paint colors based on data values.

In the given vega spec, changing the `fill` property like this should do what you are expecting if data has Positive quadrant C values also.

```
          "fill": { "signal": "datum.C > 0 ? 'green': 'red'"},
```

Comment: Blimey that was easier than I expected it would be! :)

Comment: You don't by any chance know how I'd insert labels over each hypotenuse displaying a calculated value, do you?

Comment: e.g. Pre-risk = datum.C x datum.L

Comment: `https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/text/` with `x` and `y` being the midpoint of C and L respectively. Based on negative C or positive C, set th `align` property to left or right respectively.

Comment: Thanks cruxer, very helpful! :)